# Direct access to the wysiwig images?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.0, external-images

Is there any way to get to an image uploader/manger type screen for the wysiwig images? There seems to be some sort of manager in place that the wysiwig editor uses to allow you to browse, upload and link images back into the editor (which appears to be broken btw, in v2.2.x) but I can't seem to find any direct way to just go view this manager by itself.

As we are setting up a new website, occasionally a third party or partner site (such as google, facebook, etc) needs a url to things like logo images and the like. If they need it at a specific size that is different from other logos we already use in content pages, we need to create a modified version and upload it somewhere that is accessible by the third-party in question or whatever mechanism they are using to display it.

Thus far, we have had to open up some kind of content page, pretend to be linking an image into some document, then not save the change in order to upload an image into the wysiwig file space. Isn't there any direct way to just open this image manager/uploader?

SW

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any native way to display the media storage manager aside from the method you already outlined.

A better alternative in my opinion would be to use FTP or SFTP. /pub/media/ is the storage root, and there's a wysiwyg directory inside which is where files uploaded in the admin wysiwyg end up by default.

If you're not familiar with FTP your hosting provider support can likely help you set it up. It's easy to use once you get it set up.